# parse datetime which stores ms.us

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I am attempting to parse some logfiles stored from a piece of test equipment (CANbus logger)
Within the exported TSV file they unfortunately store the absolute time in a `HH:MM:SS.XXX.YYY` format

where **XXX is in ms** and **YYY is in µs** eg: `13:58.06.286.591`

had this been `HH:MM:SS.XXXXXX` I could have use the standard datetime module to parse it via:

```
 str2date = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

and added this as a column converter **converters = {2: str2date}**

How best to manage this date format?

1. edit a copy of the file to remove the addition decimal place  -least preferred option
2. change the lambda into a full function and the function removes the last period - viable
3. some other clever way to enhance string to date

Comment: Why not use the lambda to only parse the first 12 characters?

Comment: @norie because you'll lose (microsecond) precision

Comment: exactly. the piece of test equipment can log CAN activity at 50us accuracy. This is key when you are analyzing a multicast bus and when things are occurring. On an individual node basis, this level of accuracy isn't important. However, the type of information I am extracting from a specific node I do need ~ 200ms precision and while I could just drop the us part I thought it would be best to query how to deal fully for when I need to perform bus analysis not payload analysis

Comment: To keep that level of accuracy you could add the last 4 characters `datetime.strptime(x[:12]+x[13:], '%H:%M.%S.%f')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write a simple formatter that removes the rightmost dot, so you can parse with `%f`.

***Ex:***

```
formatter = lambda x: x[::-1].replace('.', '', 1)[::-1]

s = "13:58.06.286.591"

print(formatter(s))
# 13:58.06.286591
```

Now you could integrate this like

```
from datetime import datetime

str2date = lambda x: datetime.strptime(formatter(x), '%H:%M.%S.%f')

print(str2date(s))
# 1900-01-01 13:58:06.286591
```

...or do it all in one go, depending on how much flexibility you want.

Comment: ahhh cascade lambda's ... obviously.  I was dreading doing some silly function to take the string, remove the final . and parse via the lamba. This essencially does what I intended but compact. Thankyou

Comment: @Naib glad I could help - doing it all in one function would also work (I wouldn't say that's silly ;-)). Using the lambdas is nice if you like the functional style though.